# iOS crash reason is “forbid application start”

Tags: ios, crash, hook

```
name:
NSInternalInconsistencyException

reason:
forbid application start

callStackSymbols:(

    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000181ededc8 <redacted> + 148
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000181543f80 objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000181edec80 <redacted> + 0
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001828641c0 <redacted> + 88
    4   emmlib                              0x0000000100224330 __28+[UUAppstartHook exitIfNeed]_block_invoke + 192
    5   emmlib                              0x000000010021025c __56+[UIUtils registerLocalNotification:describe:completed:]_block_invoke + 356
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001819294bc <redacted> + 24
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018192947c <redacted> + 16
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018192eb84 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1844
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000181e94d50 <redacted> + 12
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000181e92bb8 <redacted> + 1628
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000181dbcc50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001836a4088 GSEventRunModal + 180
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001870a6088 UIApplicationMain + 204
    14  emmlib                              0x00000001002244b8 uusafe_UIApplicationMain + 356
    15  MailBox                             0x00000001000ddca0 MailBox + 482464
    16  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000018195a8b8 <redacted> + 4)
```

The above is the crash log. The line 4 and line 5 are very strange, and the `[UUAppstartHook exitIfNeed]` and `[UIUtils registerLocalNotification:describe:completed:]` are not functions in my code. Are they hook function to test my application? if so, how they did that? 
By the way, the "MailBox" (in line 15) is my application’s name.

Answer (score 0):

These methods are most likely part of some library that you are using. So hunt down which third party libraries you are using, and if any uses a prefix "UU" or calls itself emmlib. Quite possibly this is a library that you are using without source code.

Comment: Thanks for your guides. I'm pretty sure that it didn't use any third party libraries.  and I still think it is the user (his registered name begin with uu) use the hook functions in some way. But I don't know how they did it.